# c++ natvis, как обратиться к функции шаблонного параметра

Tags: c++

```
<Type Name="Eigen::PlainObjectBase&lt;*&gt;">
    <DisplayString>{{ {$T1.size()} }}</DisplayString>  // <--
    <Expand>
      <ArrayItems>
        <Size>3</Size>
        <ValuePointer>m_storage.m_data.array</ValuePointer>
      </ArrayItems>
    </Expand>
  </Type>
```

В строке 2 (помечена) не получается обратиться к шаблонному типу, чтобы вызвать функцию. Как это сделать правильно?

Comment: Может я чего-то не понимаю, но.... Это точно с++??

Comment: Если автор все же хочет получить помощь, ему нужно указать правильные метки. Иначе велика вероятность того .что вопрос даже не увидят те, кто мог бы помочь.